# How can I have a JSP application display an HTML page while a Java Servlet executes a task?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP application that runs Java code through a servlet. The java task takes a good amount of time (5-10 minutes) and hangs the screen while it executes. I know that I can use asyncContext to start another thread in the background, but this still creates a hang time of about 30 seconds before forwarding to the main page. Instead, I would like to compromise with a simple "Application is Running" page during the task execution.

So my question: is it possible to display an HTML page on the screen without leaving the Servlet context? If not, what might be a better approach?

Comment: try using websockets or using javascript to `poll` - servlets are not designed for long running operations.

Comment: Use multithreading

Comment: @Scary Wombat polling looks like the best option. Thank you!